# Curious behavior with TLS RabbitMQ in Kubernetes and externalIP

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, rabbitmq

I deployed a RabbitMQ (from the helm chart https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/rabbitmq) in a Kubernetes cluster, in namespace named `rabbitmq`. I added 3 IPs (the IPs of my Kubernetes nodes) as externalIPs in rabbitmq service.
Here is the rabbitmq service :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: rabbitmq
    app.kubernetes.io/name: rabbitmq
    helm.sh/chart: rabbitmq-6.15.0
  name: rabbitmq
  namespace: rabbitmq
spec:
  externalIPs:
  - x.x.x.x1
  - x.x.x.x2
  - x.x.x.x3
  ports:
  - name: epmd
    port: 4369
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: epmd
  - name: amqp
    port: 5672
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: amqp
  - name: amqp-ssl
    port: 5671
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: amqp-ssl
  - name: dist
    port: 25672
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: dist
  - name: stats
    port: 15672
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: stats
  - name: metrics
    port: 9419
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: metrics
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: rabbitmq
    app.kubernetes.io/name: rabbitmq
    helm.sh/chart: rabbitmq-6.15.0
  type: ClusterIP
```

I have an external load balancer which target these 3 IPs. I have a DNS entry "rabbitmq.mycompagny.com" which target my load balancer. I always use this mecanism to target all my ingresses without any problem.

Finally, I have a test pod in a namespace `test`, with amqp-tools installed.
On this test pod, see some commands and results :

```sh
amqp-get --url=amqps://user:password@rabbitmq.rabbitmq.svc.cluster.local:5671 --cacert=/opt/bitnami/rabbitmq/certs/ca_certificate.pem --key=/opt/bitnami/rabbitmq/certs/server_key.pem --cert=/opt/bitnami/rabbitmq/certs/server_certificate.pem --queue=test --ssl
# opening socket to rabbitmq.rabbitmq.svc.cluster.local:5671

# => KO

# logs from rabbitmq :
#2020-01-29 07:34:25.308 [debug] <0.3077.0> accepting AMQP connection <0.3077.0> (10.244.96.29:42620 -> 10.244.32.52:5671)
#2020-01-29 07:34:25.308 [debug] <0.3077.0> closing AMQP connection <0.3077.0> (10.244.96.29:42620 -> 10.244.32.52:5671):
#connection_closed_with_no_data_received

amqp-get --url=amqps://user:password@rabbitmq.mycompagny.com:5671 --cacert=/opt/bitnami/rabbitmq/certs/ca_certificate.pem --key=/opt/bitnami/rabbitmq/certs/server_key.pem --cert=/opt/bitnami/rabbitmq/certs/server_certificate.pem --queue=test --ssl

# => OK

# logs from rabbitmq :
#2020-01-29 07:37:47.430 [info] <0.23936.4> accepting AMQP connection <0.23936.4> (10.244.32.0:55694 -> 10.244.32.28:5671)
#2020-01-29 07:37:47.472 [debug] <0.23936.4> User 'user' authenticated successfully by backend rabbit_auth_backend_internal
#2020-01-29 07:37:47.486 [info] <0.23936.4> closing AMQP connection <0.23936.4> (10.244.32.0:55694 -> 10.244.32.28:5671, vhost: '/', user: 'user')

amqp-get --url=amqp://user:password@rabbitmq.rabbitmq.svc.cluster.local:5672 --queue=test

# => OK

amqp-get --url=amqp://user:password@rabbitmq.mycompagny.com:5672 --queue=test
#opening socket to rabbitmq.mycompagny.fr:5672

# => OK
```

The difference between these commands is the target DNS. With TLS, when I use the external DNS, it's ok, but it's not the case with the internal DNS. Can you explain why ?

I double checked the certificate, which is a signed wildcard certificate (check with openssl s_server/s_client).

I have to use externalIPs focused by an external load balancer to access rabbitmq since Kubernetes ingresses only support HTTP/HTTPS protocol and the rabbitmq protocol is AMQP/AMPQS.

Comment: Why are you targeting k8s nodes not services? You need to provide detailed info about your cluster. In what namespace is the pod and service you are using for endpoint?

Comment: Crou, I edited the post. Do you need other information ?

Comment: Generally, it is inadvisable to use TLS within the safe zone boundaries... and I can't imagine a valid scenario where you would expose RabbitMQ outside of the safe zone. Why are you using TLS?

Comment: Because I need access to this RabbitMQ from another safe zone through the web...